# How to parse tuple data in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to take user input in one line in the form:

`C = (39.447; 94.657; 11.824) N = (39.292; 95.716; 11.027) Ca = (39.462; 97.101; 11.465)`

And I have to translate that so I have three variables each corresponding to the appropriate tuple. This is complicated by the semi colons and the fact that it has to be on one line.

This is what I have so far but I'm having trouble parsing it as one line, I thought eval() might work because the input resembles a variable assignment but I get "SyntaxError can't assign to literal". I feel like there should be a simple way to do this.

```
class TupleClean(str):
    def clean(self):
        new_list = []
        clean_coord = self.strip("() ")
        split_coord = clean_coord.split(";")
        for i in split_coord:
            new_list.append(float(i))
        tuple_coord = (new_list[0], new_list[1], new_list[2])
        return(tuple_coord)

coord_1 = input("Input the coordinates for carbon in the format (p; q; r): ")
coord_2 = input("Input the coordinates for nitrogen in the format (p; q; r): ")
coord_3 = input("Input the coordinates for calcium in the format (p; q; r): ")

coord_1_clean = TupleClean(coord_1)
coord_1_clean = coord_1_clean.clean()
coord_2_clean = TupleClean(coord_2)
coord_2_clean = coord_2_clean.clean()
coord_3_clean = TupleClean(coord_3)
coord_3_clean = coord_3_clean.clean()
```

Comment: Hacky way: `exec(s.replace(';', ',').replace(')', ');'))`

Comment: @Sam My program does places all the data into a dictionary for you.

Comment: @IsmailBadawi Thanks! That's exactly what I needed, I knew it was possible without regex.

Comment: `{id:[float(e) for e in re.findall(r'(\d+\.\d+)', t)] for id, t in re.findall(r'(\w+)\s*=\s*(\([^)]+\))', s)}`

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of the `tuple` class can take an iterable as an argument:

```
class TupleClean(str):
    def clean(self):
        new_list = []
        clean_coord = self.strip("() ")
        return tuple(map(float, clean_coord.split(";")))
```

(map applies the function `float` to each item of the list `clean_coord.split(";")`)

Answer (score 0):

If the input format is always the same, why not use regular expressions with capture groups and then simply convert the captured groups to floats and assign them to the three variables as three tuples?

Answer (score 0):

With regular expressions, you can take input in a single and create a dictionary `data` like so:

```
import re

regex = r'(\w+) = \(([\d.]+); ([\d.]+); ([\d.]+)\)'
data = re.findall(regex, input('Enter all data: '))
data = {i[0]:[float(j) for j in i[1:]] for i in data}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a little unusual to subclass `str` just to parse a string. I would suggest you use regex parsing.

```
COORDINATES_REGEX = re.compile(r'^\(([\d.]+);\s([\d.]+);\s([\d.]+)\)$')
match = COORDINATES_REGEX.match(coords_1)
if match is None:
     raise ValueError("Invalid input")
coords = tuple(map(float, match.groups()))
```